# reference a calculated field in mysql view

Tags: mysql, variables

Need to refer a calculated field again in the statement. Have used @ to create a variable and call it back. the statement gives a error saying "#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter" have created three variables and referred them twice. what need to be corrected in the statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view finvoice AS SELECT 
`Item_tax`,
`Date`,
`Invoice_No.`,
`Order_Id`,
`Buyer_name`,
`SKU_Code`,
`Product`,

@`price` := (round((((fkdaily.`Invoice_Amount`/ fkdaily.`Quantity`)-fkdaily.`Shipping_Charge_per_item`)/1.05),2)) as `price`,

`Quantity`,

@`vat_total` := (@price)*0.05)*Quantity),2)) As `vat_total`,

@`shipping` := (`Shipping_Charge_per_item`*`Quantity`) As `shipping`,

' ' as `roundoff`,

@`price`+@'vat_total`+@`shipping` as final

`Order_Status`,
`Invoice_No.` as `Invoice_No.2` ,
`Date` as date2,
'update_sku' as `TALLY_SKU`,
'Customer Sales (f)' As `Ledger`,
'Shipping Charges fk' As `Shipping Ledger`,
'FPC' As `Portal`

From fkdaily
```

Comment: a comma missing after this `@`price`+@'vat_total`+@`shipping` as final`

Comment: did correct that but samw issue

Comment: I see there are some `single quotes` where `back tick` is expected. For example **@`price`+@'vat_total`+@`shipping` as final** before `Order_Status`